# Is it valid MPI-3 to nest non-blocking collectives?

Tags: c, mpi

Is the following a standards-conformant MPI-3 C program?

```
#include <mpi.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int dlocalouter=1, dglobalouter=0, dlocalinner=1, dglobalinner=0;
  MPI_Request router, rinner;
  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
  MPI_Iallreduce(&dlocalouter,&dglobalouter,1,MPI_INT,MPI_SUM,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&router);
  MPI_Iallreduce(&dlocalinner,&dglobalinner,1,MPI_INT,MPI_SUM,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rinner);
  MPI_Wait(&rinner,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  MPI_Wait(&router,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without having tried it myself, that should work. What problem are you having?

Comment: The second `MPI_Wait` does not return using one MPI implementation, yet the code runs as expected with a different implementation, so I was curious whether the of code above might not be guaranteed to work by the standard, or if I should start looking for other reasons for the difference.

Comment: Sounds like you might have found a bug. MPI-3 is relatively new, and I suspect all the bugs haven't been worked out in all the libraries. I say contact the developers of the one that doesn't return.

Comment: You should probably initialize the accumulators `dglobalouter` and `dglobalinner`. It probably doesn't affect the ability of the code to run to completion, but it will affect the answer. Also, you should grab `ierr` and check it from each MPI call. Most stacks abort on error by default, but who knows what you've got there.

Comment: I will try with the initialization. I actually had checks on ierr in there but took them out to make this post more concise!

Comment: The initialization does not change anything. Seems likely enough to be a bug that I'll risk embarrassing myself by asking about the implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The reason I asked was that with a particular implementation (cray-mpich 7.0.4), in a particular environment on a particular system, the second `MPI_Wait` call would not return. This was likely due to a bug somewhere in the MPI library or a dependent communication library, and was remedied by upgrading to a newer version of the MPI implementation (cray-mpich 7.1.1).